# What enables the Raspberry Pi GPIO15(RXD0) pull-up resistor during boot?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpio

On the raspberry pi 3 all GPIO pins are powered up with a direction of "input". Each pin has a pull-up and a pull-down resistor associated with it. The status of these resistors is preserved through power loss or reset. (This is why there is no way to read the status of these resistors because they may not be known after a reset.)

I wrote a program that forces all the pull resistors to disabled so that nothing is pulling the lines high or low and then rebooted. /sys/class/gpio/*/direction and values all indicate success.

After reset, all pins came up in the input direction and without pull resistors enabled except for:

- GPIO2: pulled-up (No problem, due to externally soldered i2c pull-up
  resistor)
- GPIO3: pulled-up (No problem, due to externally soldered i2c pull-up resistor)
- GPIO14: (TXD0) pull-down resistor has been re-enabled somehow!
- GPIO15: (RXD0) pull-up resistor has been re-enabled somehow!

I have already previously used raspi-config to disable both the serial console logging and the serial uart. So I would think nothing in the boot process should alter the peripheral registers controlling GPIO14 and GPIO15.

What in the boot process is reconfiguring the GPIO15(RXD0) and GPIO14(TXD0) pins to have their pull-up/down resistors enabled and how to I stop it?

Comment: could be in the gpu bootloader or could be in the linux driver.  what happens when you load a baremetal application instead of the operating system, has it been asserted (is it the gpu code or the linux/os code?)

Comment: is it affecting you having the pull up/down registers asserted are you not using these as UARTs?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found out:

The pull-up/down resistor configurations on the broadcom chipset are non-volatile. (This is actually why you can't query what their status is in anyway; because the chip doesn't know what they are from boot time and can't query them itself. The CPU can only set them.)

So, if you turn off all the pull-up/down resistors the raspian distribution boots with all pins in the output/high-z configuration except for GPIO2 and 3 because these are the I2C pins with physical pull-up resistors soldered on board. The Tx GPIO pin also reads high but I think it due to the bluetooth system being initialized in the kernel and I don't know how to disable that.

So if you set all the pins to input/hi-z and disable pull-up/pull-down it will come up that way after reboot (unless you've enable something in the kernel or otherwise changed them after power-up)